# Store strings in binary file while keeping them alphabetically sorted

Tags: c, sorting, binaryfiles, binary-search

So, supposing I have a C program that stores strings into a binary file. And in another binary file, the position of the first byte of every string is saved.

eg. words.bin contains: alphacardelta

and pos.bin contains: 0 5 8

I want to insert "beta", and for it to go between alpha and car. While I have figured out how to insert it after alpha, I cannot figure out an automated way that will insert it in the correct position and will not result in "disappearance" of any other words in a possibly long list. Any help?

Another way that I guess could work (possibly better) is inserting beta after delta and then sorting all over again, but my attempts at this have failed too.

Any assistance appreciated.

Comment: What *have* you figured out so far?

Comment: @user253751 as stated in the answer, how to insert it after the word its supposed to go. Sometimes it works well, sometimes it overwrites other words while trying to "move them over". The reason I havent posted any code is I am constantly changing it trying to figure it out so I would have to be updating every 5 minutes. I have given this as a starting point cause it does not require code to understand.

Comment: @user253751 I prefer, if possible, to have it done the second way (resorting after inserting at the end) but I ve made zero progress there

Comment: Roughly you need to do this: once you have found out the correct position of the string to be inserted, insert it there and then increment the positions after the inserted string by the length of the inserted strings.

Comment: I suggest that you post how you think it *should* work, and then maybe we can tell you why it is wrong.

Comment: Why do you want to do this in the file directly? Use a suitable data structure that allows for quick insertion and implement reading and writing it to a file. Read the data from the file, update it as required and if it has changed, store the changed data.

Comment: @MOehm That is completely unnecessary. I see that as inefficient programming for no benefit. (yes, it's already inefficient to insert into the middle of a list in a file, but your suggestion makes it even less efficient)

Comment: Can you figure out how to do this in memory rather than in a file?

Comment: @user253751: I don't know. It's much easier than trying to fiddle with the file at byte level. To do what OP wants efficiently, you'd probably have to write to a temporary file anyway. The words are probably going to be used by the program anyway, so why not use a good data structure?

Comment: @Jabberwocky yes, I have it implemented in various programs that way, but I cant figure out how to do it directly in the file. If i insert it before incrementing as you said, then it overwrites the word that was there earlier, and maybe some letters from the one after that. And without using an array I havent managed to preserve the words that were already there.

Comment: @iRaspberryPi the answer below explains what you need to do.

Comment: @Jabberwocky so there is no way to do it without using a data structure other than creating a second file? Not that I have something in mind, just wondering

Comment: You could copy from FILE1 a to FILE2 doing the insertionm on the fly (this is easy) and then delete FILE1 and rename FILE2 to FILE1. There is no way to insert content into a file without reading the complete file one way or another

Comment: @iRaspberryPi It ***can*** be done without creating a second file and without reading the whole file into memory. It's just easier if you do one of those things. If you don't do one of those things, then of course you need to read the bytes you're going to overwrite, before you overwrite them.

Comment: @user253751 but you need to read at least everything inthe file from the inserting point onwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to insert "beta", and for it to go between alpha and car.

To do this in a file you need to write the data into the file again.

There are two methods here.

1. Read all the data from the file into memory (RAM). You can use arrays or structures.
2. Add the additional data in corrrect location into memory.
3. Write the entire file again. As an optimization you can write from the changed location to the end.

Alternatively you can

1. Read all the data from the file into memory (RAM). Here you can read the entire data or in suitable chunks to reduce memory usage.
2. create a new file with the additional data
3. write to this new file.
4. At the end you can delete the old file and rename the new file.

This is a very inefficient operation and the it would be better if you try to find a way to only add new data to the end of the file (append). You can keep some sort of index of the data in the beginning to know the location of the string and if it is deleleted or not.

Comment: If you wanted to use less memory you can insert directly into the file by reading and writing part of the file at a time. It would be more difficult.

Comment: @user253751 i think i am going to try reading up to alpha, spotting that it has to go after alpha, storing, or somehow saving, cardelta somewhere and then deleting them from the file, then appending beta, then appending cardelta again. and just incrementing the positions in pos.bin by length of beta. Is this inefficient?

Comment: @iRaspberryPi - Since you already have an index in `pos.bin` file you can always write to the main file at the end. You can then sort the positions and only rewrite the `pos.bin` file every time.